# Extract data from an xml attribute with multiple data

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have this XML data with a tag with an attribute that is filled with informations

```
<Start>
<TestCase>
    <GenericItem html="&lt;table border=&quot;1&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th rowspan=&quot;2&quot;&gt;Environment&lt;br/&gt;(Linux)&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th&gt;Check Execution Time [sec]&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th&gt;Memory consumption [Mb]&lt;/th&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th&gt;Baseline - M4A4b&lt;br/&gt;(mean of #run(s))&lt;/td&gt;&lt;th&gt;Baseline - M4A4b&lt;br/&gt;init / mean / max&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th&gt;MATLAB&lt;/th&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;2.4 (10)&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;557 / 573 / 575&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th&gt;MCR&lt;/th&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;2.3699 (10)&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;249 / 295 / 297&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;green&quot;&gt;No numerical differences between 'MATLAB - M4A4b' and 'MCR - M4B2b' found.&lt;/font&gt;">
       Results for 'A3 Item - CT07':
      </GenericItem>
</testcase>
</Start>
```

I need help on how to parse in Python and get only the Text `Results for 'A3 Item - CT07':` and `No numerical differences between 'MATLAB - M4A4b' and 'MCR - M4B2b' found.` which is inside the HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange situation where a whole html table is embedded within an attribute of an element in a parent html document....

Having said that, you can try this:

```
import lxml.html as lh
generic = """your html above""""

doc = lh.fromstring(generic)

#to get your "results", try either

print(doc.xpath('normalize-space(//genericitem/text())'))

#or

print(doc.xpath('//genericitem/text()')[0].strip())
```

In either case, the output should be

```
Results for 'A3 Item - CT07':
```

The other one requires a little more work: first extract the embedded html, then parse it and look for your target:

```
table = lh.fromstring(doc.xpath('//genericitem/@html')[0])
```

Then either

```
print(table.xpath('normalize-space(//font/text())'))
```

or

```
print(table.xpath('//font/text()')[0].strip())
```

The output should be

```
No numerical differences between 'MATLAB - M4A4b' and 'MCR - M4B2b' found.
```